# LayoutManager that fills all RecyclerView area

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView`. I would like to achieve following (each circle is one `RecyclerView` item):

[image]

Each circle might have differing size.

I tried to use `GridLayoutManager` but it turns out that I need to provide a `spanCount` which is something does not fit my case.

Comment: Please check this link https://github.com/nex3z/FlowLayout.

Answer (score 1):

For the RecycleView layouts in a grid form with different cell spans can be achieved by using the [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager). You will find many [tutorials](https://android.jlelse.eu/asymmetrical-grid-layout-using-recyclerview-5ed44899d7b5) in the internet about how to implement it.

```
GridLayoutManager  layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 6);

layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        // Use whatever logic you need here to decide how 
        //  many columns to span for any given row position
        if (position % 2)
            return 3;
        else
            return 6;
    }
});
```

Then in onBindViewHolder update the LayoutParams.width of each view as you may require.

Comment: I also tried this earlier. This layout manager also required `spanCount` which problematic is because I do not know the count of both coloumns and rows.

Comment: getting Cannot resolve method 'setSpanSizeLookup(anonymous android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup)` error.

Comment: I dont think that you can set `setSpanSizeLookup` for `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`.

Comment: Then for such case is better to use a GridLayoutManager, and update the views metrics when binding them. So use the lookup to specify how many columns a row must span, and the onBindViewHolder to update the individual views metrics to render accordingly the required columns area.

Comment: Added a link to a tutorial.

Comment: Did not really help. Thank you anyways for your effort!